# Comparing values of equal-length tuple and list

Tags: python

I have a function that compares the values of a tuple and a list of equal length. It compares each value in `combination` to see if it is equal to its respective value in the `path` or if the value in `combination` is '*', that is valid.

So for example: `combination=('dog', 'cat', '*')`, `path=['dog', 'cat', 'bird']` would return `True`.

What I have is below and works fine, but is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
def _is_valid_combination(combination, path):
    """
    Check if the combination is valid for the path

    Keyword arguments:
    combination -- tuple of pattern combination
    path -- list of the actual path
    """
    index = 0
    for part in combination:
        if (part == path[index]) or ('*' == part):
            index += 1
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood your code correctly, you can do this trivially with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def _is_valid_combination(combination, path):
    """
    Check if the combination is valid for the path

    Keyword arguments:
    combination -- tuple of pattern combination
    path -- list of the actual path
    """
    return all(part == '*' or part == path_ for part, path_ in zip(combination, path))
```

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe! This is exactly the simple thing I was looking for! I overlooked `all`. Cheers!